# How to install ubuntu from usb?

Tags: boot, usb

I want to install ubuntu on my crashed windows xp from usb..I made usb bootable and trying to install but now I stuck on grub command..I don't know what to type...please help. Thanks

Comment: it'll be helpful if you could elaborate. which step are you stuck on? what is the process you followed? which Ubuntu version?

Comment: You should not see the grub command line. Maybe something went wrong when creating the bootable stick. If you have a Ubuntu system, I'd use the tool supplied with Ubuntu to make the stick bootable. If you only have Windows, follow this guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

In both cases make sure to safely remove the stick (or leave it plugged in when rebooting).

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

let's check out [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) you could do it with your senses.